# Birational map between a conic and an affine line (related to the classical formula of Pythagorean triples)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Could someone please explain me the following?

It says in the notes I am reading that
$$
Spec \ (\mathbb{Q}[x,y] / (x^2 + y^2-1) ) \rightarrow Spec \ \mathbb{Q}[m]
$$
given by 
$$
f : (x,y) \rightarrow y/(x-1)
$$
for $x \not = 1$
and
$$
g : m \rightarrow ((m^2-1)/(m^2 + 1), -2m/(m^2 + 1))
$$
away from $m^2 + 1 = 0$, gives that the two schemes are birational.

This is related to the classical formula of Pythagorean triples.
I am confused with how to show that these maps are birational.
Could someone please explain me how this works?

Thank you!

ps I am quite confused with how $f$ and $g$ are defined as well... I am not even sure if these maps are supposed to be for the schemes or for the coordinate rings?

Comment: For stuff like this you probably want to draw a picture and pretend that you can work with just points like $(a, b) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$. One great thing about schemes is that this is often okay. The map $f$ is assigning to each point on the rational circle the slope of the line between that point and $(1, 0)$. The formulas and the picture are sort of hinting at where these things are undefined. You should be able to get a real isomorphism of two open sets — I think this is probably the easiest thing, although showing that there's an isomorphism of function fields would be okay too.

Comment: To add: the formula for the ring map (going in the opposite direction) and the formula for the map on "classical points" is usually the same thing. The non-classical points come along for the ride, so to speak.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you very much!!